# Kafka Metrics | Why i see additional node ids node--1 and node--2 in metrics report

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have two brokers with ids 1001 and 1002. In the out of the producer performance tool, the per-node metrics section displays metrics for node--1 and node--2 while my broker ids are 1001 and 1002. What is node--1/node--2 value? how should I interpret these metric values?

producer-node-metrics:incoming-byte-rate:{client-id=producer-1, node-id=**node--1**}                : 5.388
producer-node-metrics:incoming-byte-rate:{client-id=producer-1, node-id=**node--2**}                : 44.175
producer-node-metrics:incoming-byte-rate:{client-id=producer-1, node-id=node-1001}              : 59489.855
producer-node-metrics:incoming-byte-rate:{client-id=producer-1, node-id=node-1002}              : 7739.021

Answer (score 3):

Nodes with a negative ID are nodes obtained from the bootstrap servers configuration.

Addresses in `bootstrap.servers` are used to discover the cluster. So the client connects to them to retrieve the cluster metadata. Once done, clients re-establish connections to the nodes they have discovered and use these new connections for all traffic. The bootstrap connections are usually not reused and dropped later.

---

Not asked here but related:

If you look at consumers you may also notice nodes with really large IDs (such as `node-2147483646`). These denote connections to group coordinators nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and additional info.